# A weird exception using sbt-pack and scala 2.10.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am trying to compile and assemble a scala project with sbt-pack, this is the build [sbt](http://pastebin.com/xFh3uCZ9) file and this is the [plugins.sbt](http://pastebin.com/7V2FSnyg).

The project has two subprojects, common and main, common has this structure:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:common aironman$ ls src/main/scala/common/utils/cassandra/
CassandraConnectionUri.scala    Helper.scala            Pillar.scala
```

main has this one:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ ls main/src/main/scala/
com common
```

Inside com folder, i have this folders:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ ls main/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/
Collect.scala       ExamineAndTrain.scala   Predict.scala       Utils.scala
```

Where Collect, ExamineAndTrain and Predict are object with main functions.

Inside common folder, i have this:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ ls main/src/main/scala/common/utils/cassandra/
CassandraMain.scala
```

The project compiles and i can pack it generating some folders under target folder. This is the [set of folders](http://pastebin.com/ntKUK5Nr) and the libs under /target/pack/lib.

The problem happens when i try to run the  generated command:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ target/pack/bin/collect /tmp/tweets 10000 10 1
Initializing Streaming Spark Context...
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/03/15 11:02:54 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at org.apache.spark.util.TimeStampedWeakValueHashMap.<init>(TimeStampedWeakValueHashMap.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:277)
at com.databricks.apps.twitter_classifier.Collect$.main(Collect.scala:37)
at com.databricks.apps.twitter_classifier.Collect.main(Collect.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
16/03/15 11:02:54 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

Spark almost is able to start, but it finally crashes.
I know that the most probable problem here is some libraries are compiled against scala 2.10 and others are compiled against 2.11, but, in my build.sbt file i am providing scalaVersion := "2.10.4" in val commonSettings and val sparkDependencies is set to NOT use %provided%, i can see every spark jar files compiled with 2.10:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ ls    target/pack/lib/spark*
target/pack/lib/spark-catalyst_2.10-1.4.0.jar                              

target/pack/lib/spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.4.0.jar

target/pack/lib/spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar                       

target/pack/lib/spark-sql_2.10-1.4.0.jar

target/pack/lib/spark-graphx_2.10-1.4.0.jar                     

target/pack/lib/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.4.0.jar

target/pack/lib/spark-launcher_2.10-1.4.0.jar                         

target/pack/lib/spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.0.jar

target/pack/lib/spark-mllib_2.10-1.4.0.jar                      

target/pack/lib/spark-twitter-lang-classifier-using-cassandra_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

target/pack/lib/spark-network-common_2.10-1.4.0.jar                 

target/pack/lib/spark-unsafe_2.10-1.4.0.jar
```

UPDATE

I can see this scala libraries in lib folder:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ ls  target/pack/lib/scala*

**target/pack/lib/scala-async_2.11-0.9.1.jar    

target/pack/lib/scala-library-2.11.1.jar**  

target/pack/lib/scalap-2.10.0.jar

target/pack/lib/scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar   

target/pack/lib/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar
```

the question now is, theoretically i am compiling with 2.10.4, so, how is it possible that scala-library-2.11.1 and scala-async_2.11-0.9.1.jar are within lib folder?

how can i force to use the correct versions?

UPDATE 2

the problem was related with wrong version of "com.chrisomeara" % "pillar_2.11" % "2.0.1". The correct version is "com.chrisomeara" % "pillar_2.10" % "2.0.1"

This setting is the correct one and now i can see the right scala libraries:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ ls  target/pack/lib/scala*

target/pack/lib/scala-async_2.10-0.9.1.jar  
target/pack/lib/scala-library-2.10.6.jar    
target/pack/lib/scalap-2.10.0.jar
target/pack/lib/scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar   
target/pack/lib/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar
```

Now there is another exception, but i think it is another problem not related with this one, so thank you Yuval.

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:my-twitter-cassandra-app aironman$ target/pack/bin/collect /tmp/tweets 10000 10 1
Initializing Streaming Spark Context...
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/03/15 11:39:12 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
16/03/15 11:39:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/15 11:39:12 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:368)
at com.databricks.apps.twitter_classifier.Collect$.main(Collect.scala:37)
at com.databricks.apps.twitter_classifier.Collect.main(Collect.scala)
16/03/15 11:39:12 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:368)
at com.databricks.apps.twitter_classifier.Collect$.main(Collect.scala:37)
at com.databricks.apps.twitter_classifier.Collect.main(Collect.scala)
16/03/15 11:39:12 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: *I know that the most probable problem here is some libraries are compiled against scala 2.10 and others are compiled against 2.11* You need all the libs you're using to be compiled agains't spark 2.10, not 2.11. Add your `build.sbt`.

Comment: Hi Yuval, thank you for the quick response, this is my build.sbt file http://pastebin.com/xFh3uCZ9

Comment: Well, for example: `"com.chrisomeara" % "pillar_2.11" % "2.0.1"` compiles agains't 2.11. That won't work.

Comment: thank you man, how stupid I was not to have realized that detail!